# Testing ServletFilter with Mockito using a response wrapper

Tags: java, filter, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for a filter I've written. This sounds simple enough but there is a bit I can't quite figure out which is setting the status code of the ServletResponse. Unfortunately this is complicated because I'm using an HttpServletResponseWrapper as I need to check the response status code (as I need to override it and return a 200). For reference I'm getting back a IncludedResponse which does have a getStatusCode() but for some reason in the JDK source it returns 0?!? Anyway, here's part of the filter I have:

```
private void handleUploadFilePost(ServletResponse servletResponse, HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    RequestWrapper requestWrapper = new RequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
    ResponseWrapper responseWrapper = new ResponseWrapper(httpServletResponse);
    String requestBodyTrimmed = getRequestBody(requestWrapper.getInputStream());
    Case caseDetails = requestBodyMappingHelper.mapRequestBody(requestBodyTrimmed, Case.class);
    filterChain.doFilter(requestWrapper, responseWrapper);
    if (responseWrapper.getStatus() >= 400 && responseWrapper.getStatus() <= 599) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this creates issues when testing. If it was a simple ServletResponse I mock it and do...

```
when(myServletResponse).getStatus().thenReturn(...)
```

However, because I'm creating the custom wrapper for the status it seems to make it seemingly impossible to set the status code of this local variable as it's held as an int in the wrapper which overrides the HttpServletResponse setStatus.

Therefore is there anything I can use with Mockito or Powermock to do what I want to do here? When the HttpServletResponse value is set, it overrides that and stores the state in my wrapper, but I can't get it to work. I've experimented with the following:

```
doAnswer(new Answer() {
    public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
        servletResponse.setStatus(400);
        return null; // void method, so return null
    }
}).when(filterChain).doFilter(Mockito.any(ServletRequest.class), Mockito.any(ServletResponse.class));
```

But this doesn't work for some reason. The ServletResponse in the test is not mocked and I'm actually creating it so that it triggers off it's setStatus() which will be intercepted by the Wrapper;

```
private IncludedResponse servletResponse;

servletResponse = new IncludedResponse();
servletResponse.setProxiedHttpServletResponse(new IncludedResponse());
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

> when(myServletResponse).getStatus().thenReturn(...)

The correct for is

when(myServletResponse.getStatus()**)**.thenReturn(...)

or change to the more general form:

```
doReturn(...).when(myServletResponse).getStatus()
```

which also allows trowing exception on void methods:

```
doThrow(new *Exception())when(mock).veoidMethod();
```

---

> I can't do that either (the doReturn) part as how can I mock the wrapper as a local variable. That's why I need to set the original ServletResponse.setStatus method

You could easily use a local mock if you would apply *dependency injection*.

Comment: Thanks, made a mistake in my original post. I can't do that though for reasons mentioned above.

Comment: To your update message, I can't do that either (the doReturn) part as how can I mock the wrapper as a local variable. That's why I need to set the original ServletResponse.setStatus method which will trigger my wrapper override to set it's value. Otherwise yes it will mock the value, but it won't be picked up in the actual filter which uses the wrapper (as the servletResponse doesn't have any way to get the statusCode for the reasons mentioned above..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why I didn't think of this before. What I can do is create my own filter chain:

```
FilterChain filterChain = new FilterChain() {
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (servletResponse instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) servletResponse).setStatus(400);
        }
    }
};
```

That way when the response comes back, I don't need to mock it or anything but I'm actually getting the response object which the wrapper uses. So much easier than trying to do it using mocking (if it was possible in the first place).

Thanks Timothy for your comment. I'll leave this here in case anyone else has a brain block like me!